# Is there a Unix command that searches for similar strings, based mostly on how they sound when spoken?

Tags: search, text, pattern-matching, natural-language

I have a file of names, and I want to search within it, not caring too much about whether I have spelled the name ( that I am searching for ) correctly.  I know that `grep` has quite a bit of functionality to search for a whole slew of similar strings within a file or stream, but as far as I am aware, it does not have functionality to correct for spelling errors, and even if it did, since these are names of people, they wouldn't be found inside a standard dictionary.

Perhaps I can make my file of names into a special dictionary, and then use some standard spell checking tool?  Of particular importance in this application is the ability to match similarly sounding words.

For example: `"jacob"` should return `"Jakob"`.  Even better would be if inter-language similarities were also accounted for, so that `"miguel"` should match `"Michael"`.

Is this something that has been implemented already, or will I have to build my own?

Comment: `agrep` for approximate `grep` (not for sound/language). Also in `zsh` pattern matching `(#a3)` for allow up to 3 mistakes.

Comment: Take a look at the [`Text::Soundex`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Text/Soundex.html) `perl` core module too: http://pastebin.com/UbeVFBQA

Comment: @manatwork - you should write that up as an answer!

Comment: @slm, not sure how useful that can be in practice. For example “miguel”, “Michael”, “michelle”, “majkul” and “mysql” all have soundex code “M240”. When I tried to use it, I discovered that its too broad to be useful for most tasks. So I better let someone capable to fine tune it to make it an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@manatwork has it right, soundex is probably the tool you're looking for.

Install the perl Soundex module using CPAN:

```
$ sudo cpan Text::Soundex
CPAN: Storable loaded ok (v2.27)
....
Text::Soundex is up to date (3.04).
```

Make a file full of names to test called `names.txt`

```
jacob
Jakob
miguel
Michael
```

Now the perl script to use the Soundex module, `soundslike.pl`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Text::Soundex;

open(FH, 'names.txt');

$targetSoundex=soundex($ARGV[0]);
print "Target soundex of $ARGV[0] is $targetSoundex\n";

while(<FH>) {
    chomp;
    print "Soundex of $_ is ".soundex($_);
    if($targetSoundex eq soundex($_)) {
        print " (match).\n";
    }else {
        print " (no match).\n";
    }
}
close(FH);
```

Make it executable and run some examples:

```
$ chmod +x soundslike.pl 
$ ./soundslike.pl michael
Target soundex of michael is M240
Soundex of jacob is J210 (no match).
Soundex of Jakob is J210 (no match).
Soundex of miguel is M240 (match).
Soundex of Michael is M240 (match).
$ ./soundslike.pl jagub
Target soundex of jagub is J210
Soundex of jacob is J210 (match).
Soundex of Jakob is J210 (match).
Soundex of miguel is M240 (no match).
Soundex of Michael is M240 (no match).
```