# How to use soundex search in file searching?

Tags: filenames, file-search, text-to-speech

I have a directory that contains numerous files. Moreover, I forget exact file name. So, when I want to find a file I don't find it.

If there is any tool that use soundex algorithm for searching that is helpful for my case.

Comment: Related: [Is there a Unix command that searches for similar strings, based mostly on how they sound when spoken](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79377/is-there-a-unix-command-that-searches-for-similar-strings-based-mostly-on-how-t)

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I have seen that. But it works for string contained by a file.

Comment: It's easy to change that perl script to omit the `open(FH, 'names.txt');` statement and change `<FH>` to `<>`, so it'll read stdin. Then, you can put two tools together in a pipeline: `find /path/to/my/directory -type f | /path/to/perlscript`.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, Do you mean `open(FH, <>)`?

Comment: Delete the `open(FH, 'names.txt');`  line, and change `while(<FH>)`  to `while(<>)`.

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer written for my own curiosity.  You should probably build something out of the suggestions in the answers to "[Is there a Unix command that searches for similar strings, based mostly on how they sound when spoken?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79377/is-there-a-unix-command-that-searches-for-similar-strings-based-mostly-on-how-t)" (the Perl `Text::Soundex` module) instead of using this.

---

The following shell script and accompanying `sed` script does a Soundex filename search in the directory tree rooted at the current directory given a search string on the command line.

```
$ sh soundex.sh fissbux
./fizzbuzz
./fizzbuzz.c
./fizzbuzz2
./fizzbuzz2.c

$ sh soundex.sh sharlok
./HackerRank/Algorithms/02-Implementation/17-sherlock_and_squares.c

$ sh soundex.sh sundek
./soundex.sh
./soundex.sed
```

The shell script (`soundex.sh`):

```
#!/bin/sh

soundex=$( printf '%s\n' "$1" | tr 'a-z' 'A-Z' | sed -f soundex.sed )

find . -exec bash -c '
    paste <( printf "%s\n" "${@##*/}" | tr "a-z" "A-Z" | sed -f soundex.sed ) \
          <( printf "%s\n" "$@" ) |
    awk -vs="$0" "\$1 == s" | cut -f 2-' "$soundex" {} +
```

The script calculates the soundex value for the search term using the `sed` script (below). It then uses `find` to find all names in the current directory or below and calculates the soundex value for each in the same way as for the search term. If a soundex value for a filename matches that of the search term, the full path to that file is printed.

I admit that the shell script is a bit basic.  For example, it may be improved by adding the absolute path to the `soundex.sed` script. As it is written now, it requires that the `sed` script is in the current directory. It also does not support filenames containing newlines.

The `sed` script (`soundex.sed`):

```
s/[^[:alpha:]]//g
h
s/^\(.\).*$/\1/
x
y/bfpvBFPVcgjkqsxzCGJKQSXZdtDTlLmnMNrR/111111112222222222222222333344555566/
s/\([1-6]\)[hwHW]\1/\1/g
s/\([1-6]\)\1\1*/\1/g
s/[aeiouyhwAEIOUYHW]/!/g
s/^.//
H
x
s/\n//
s/!//g
s/^\(....\).*$/\1/
s/^\(...\)$/\10/
s/^\(..\)$/\100/
s/^\(.\)$/\1000/
```

This implements "American Soundex" [as described in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex#American_Soundex). It does not modify the initial character (apart from deleting it if it's not alphabetic), which is why I uppercase the strings with `tr` in the shell script.

This has not been thoroughly tested, but seems to correctly handle the names mentioned in the Wikipedia article.

Annotated version (the "steps" refers to the steps in the abovementioned Wikipedia article):

```
# Remove non-alphabetic characters
s/[^[:alpha:]]//g

# STEP 1 (part 1: retain first character)

# Save whole line in hold-space
h

# Delete everything but the first character and swap with hold-space
s/^\(.\).*$/\1/
x

# The hold-space now contains only the first character

# STEP 2

y/bfpvBFPVcgjkqsxzCGJKQSXZdtDTlLmnMNrR/111111112222222222222222333344555566/

# STEP 3

s/\([1-6]\)[hwHW]\1/\1/g
s/\([1-6]\)\1\1*/\1/g

# STEP 1 (part 2: remove vowels etc.)

# We don't actually remove them but "mask" them with "!"
# This avoids accidentally deleting the first character later
s/[aeiouyhwAEIOUYHW]/!/g

# Replace first character with the one saved in the hold-space

# Delete first character
s/^.//

# Append pattern-space to hold-space and swap
H
x

# Remove newline inserted by "H" above and all "!" (old vowels etc.)
s/\n//
s/!//g

# STEP 4

s/^\(....\).*$/\1/
s/^\(...\)$/\10/
s/^\(..\)$/\100/
s/^\(.\)$/\1000/
```

---

Searching with soundex values mostly comes down to luck.

---

Also:

```
$ paste <( printf '%s\n' * | sed -f soundex.sed ) <( printf '%s\n' * )
F236    Factorio
F230    Fasta
G500    Game
H265    HackerRank
K200    KEYS
L210    Lisp
P625    Parsing
P315    Pathfinder
P315    Pathfinder.tar.xz
Q000    QA
R165    Reformat
R123    Repositories
R564    RimWorld
S613    Scripts
U523    UNIX.dot
U521    UNIX.png
U523    UNIX.txt
W620    Work
a526    answers.txt
c313    cat-food-schedule.txt
f212    fizzbuzz
f212    fizzbuzz.c
f212    fizzbuzz2
f212    fizzbuzz2.c
p363    poetry.txt
q235    questions.txt
r200    rc
s532    soundex.sed
s532    soundex.sh
u313    utp-1.0.tar.gz
```